# Reducing minimum-weight $f$-subfactors to minimum-weight perfect matching

Tags: algorithms, matching-theory, perfect-matchings

> **Question:**
>
> What is known about reducing the calculation of minimum-weight $f$-subfactors of symmetric graphs in the presence of negative edge weights to minimum-weight perfect matching?

By a $f$-subfactor I mean regular subgraphs with vertex degree $f$ whose vertices and edges are subsets of the respective sets of the "original" graph.

I am specifically interested in the most "conservative" transformations of the original graph, that represent the sought reduction; by "conservative" I mean the least number of generated additional vertices and edges.